# remove listener from injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection, opera-extension

I have Opera sidebar extension
and when extension is fired (sb opened), I need to inject some code with message listener in active tab
code works fine, the problem is that if I close sidebar and open it again, I'll get another listener injected (console will log two times when message is send)...and on another reopen +1..and so on.

I tried to fix this with removing listener, but it doesn't work.
I'm still getting +1 on console for every new extension start (injecting).
And I can't place **addListener** in **removeListener** callback. Doesn't work at all
(I guess it doesn't support it in this form)

here is the code I've bee injecting:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 
    "chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(msgL);\
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msgL);\
    function msgL(msg) {\
      if (msg.test) console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');\
    }"
  }, function(result) {
    if (!result) console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

How can I clear previous listener when injecting new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `msgL` function is recreated each time so `removeListener` tries to remove this new instance instead of the previously attached one.

Store the function in the `window` object (this doesn't seem safe), the injected code would be:

```
if (window.msgL) chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(window.msgL);
window.msgL = function(msg) {
  if (msg.test) console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(window.msgL);
```

Or keep track of tab IDs with the listener attached in your extension and only add it when needed:

```
var attachedIDs = {};
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
    var id = tabs[0].id;
    if (!attachedIDs[id]) {
        attachedIDs[id] = true;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 
            "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function msgL(msg) {\
              if (msg.test) console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');\
            });"
          }, function(result) {
            if (!result) console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        });
    }
});
```

This code would save the `attachedIDs` when run in a persistent background page. Otherwise use `sessionStorage` API or `chrome.storage` API to save/restore it.

Comment: If I use window.msgL =  function(msg)... I'm getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**. There is no error if i just write **function msgL(msg).....**. So the problem is writing into a window object.Any chance to fix this?...cause I would like to avoid  storage usage (using event page)

Comment: started to work when I added **;** after anonymous function in **window.msgL**

Comment: Good catch, this is now an assignment not a scope. Usually it doesn't matter though, but evidently this is not the case. I'll add it to the answer.